# How to wrap text around image in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want my text to wrap around my image. Right now I'm using the Bootstrap 5 grid system. But this is not giving me the result I want. I've tried using 'float: right' on the image, but that didn't work.

The text should really wrap around the image that is pulled to the right.

How would you achieve this?

My code:

```
<section id="about" class="about">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-7 pt-4 pt-lg-0">
            <h3>Over mij</h3>
            <br />
            <p>
              ... text ...
            </p>
          </div>
        
          <div style="text-align: left;" class="col-lg-5">
            <img src="assets/img/fotokristin.jpg" class="img-fluid imgshadow" alt="">
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- End About Section -->
```

Comment: If you want the text to wrap around the image, then it makes no sense to put them into separate columns to begin with. And for float to work, the element that you _apply_ `float` to, must come _before_ the content that you want to flow around it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=bootstrap+wrap+text+around+image+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The image needs to be in the same `.col` as the text, before the `<p>` and use `.float-end`

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="about" class="about">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-7 pt-4 pt-lg-0">
        <h3>Over mij</h3>
        <br />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" class="float-end imgshadow" alt="">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div style="text-align: left;" class="col-lg-5">

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `float-end` or any of its variations: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/float/ Remember to avoid using `d-flex` or `d-grid`, they'll give you unexpected results over BS defaults.

Remember to add additional options to your image to make it look better, like `m-3` for margins to all the side. You can also use `<figure>`.

Example code:

```html
<p>Text.</p>

<figure class="figure w-50 float-end m-3">
    <img src="photo.jpg" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded img-thumbnail" alt="Alt text.">
    <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center">Visible text.</figcaption>
</figure>

<p>Text.</p>
```

Result:

[image]

Just in case, my image was contained here (these are just the opening tags, so you can see the related classes):

```html
   <main class="mb-4">
        <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
            <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
```

Comment: Dude that is perfect!!! Worked perfectly to me!!!!

Comment: Why avoid using flex and grid in 2023? Bootstrap is literally built on top of them and I've only ever heard the opposite - to avoid floats and prefer flex and grid.